# 1-concatenable primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

If we choose some prime, say $11$, we can concatenate one digit to the left and one to the right to obtain another prime, for example, $2113$, we can do the same with $2113$ and obtain $121139$, a prime, and so on...

Let us call some prime (written in decimal notation as $a_1...a_k$) a *$1$-concatenable* prime if there exist digits $b_1$ and $c_1$ such that $b_1a_1...a_kc_1$ is prime and digits $b_2$ and $c_2$ such that $b_2b_1a_1...a_kc_1c_2$ is prime and...and digits $b_l$ and $c_l$ such that $b_l...b_2b_1a_1...a_kc_1c_2...c_l$ is prime, and so on...

That is, a prime number is *$1$-concatenable* prime if, starting from it, we can build larger and larger primes in such a way that at each new step we concatenate one digit from the left and one from the right, and if we can repeat that process an infinite number of times.

Is there at least one *$1$-concatenable* prime?

If there is none, are there chains of arbitrary length, that is, is it true that for every $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists some prime $p$ such that $p$ is $n$ times concatenable in the described way, that is, by concatenating at each step one digit from the left and one from the right?

Comment: Posted to mse but deleted by author, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890598/1-concatenable-primes

Comment: Now posted to mse again, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891014/1-concatenable-primes. PLEASE DON'T DO THIS.

Comment: Here is some more concrete advice on posting questions to both math.stackexchange and mathoverflow: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2638/

Comment: It is not a priori clear to me that this question is decidable

Comment: For any two digit pattern $bc$ from $00$ to $99$ there is a prime $abcd $ with $a \gt 0$. The same is true for three digit patterns (in fact $909$ and $962$ can be extended two ways and everything else at least three ways.) On average there are $8$ ways each. That won't persist forever but by my back of the envelope calculations only for $n$ around $40$ digits does the expected number of completions $anz$ of $n$ to a prime fall below 1.

Comment: ... But after it falls below $1$, the number of $n$-digit survivors of the process (starting with some given initial prime) should decrease rapidly as $n$ increases, so that your initial prime will not be $1$-concatenable.  This is not a proof, but it shows that $1$-concatenable primes are unlikely to exist.

Comment: In principle, it should be possible to do a brute-force search to show that a given initial prime is not $1$-concatenable.

Comment: Does it help to work in any base other than $10$?  For instance, in binary all $1$-concatable primes must be of the form $\underbrace{0~or~1\cdots 0~or~1}_{length~k} x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \underbrace{111 \cdots 111}_{length~k}\  \forall k>1$.

Comment: Binary is easy.  If we don't allow leading $0$'s, you can only add $1$'s on the left; and since anything ending in $0$ is even, you can only add $1$'s on the right.  But $1...1_2$ with $k$ $1$'s is $2^k-1$, and this is divisible by the initial prime $p$ if $p$ is odd and $k$ is divisible by $p-1$.  The other case is where the initial $p = 2$, and this is not $1$-concatenable because $11110111_2 = 247 = 13 \cdot 19$.